# How to get stackpanel handle in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I use this code behind to get a handle of stack panel:

```
HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(imageControl) as HwndSource;
IntPtr32 handle = source.Handle;
```

is there a way to do the same thing in XAML?

Comment: What on earth would you do with a handle in XAML?

Comment: I want to send it to the ViewModel and use it there.

Comment: If you need to use an stackpanel such as parameter, you can use a Command instead of an event and pass the stackpanel in CommandParameter

Comment: if you need to send stackpanel to viewmodel, dude you are headed the wrong way .. like totally wrong way!

Comment: XAML controls aren't like winform controls. They do not have their own handles. The handle you get is the same as the handle for the window.

Comment: @Muds I DO NOT wand to send the stack panel object to the ViewModel! Just its' handle value converted to int32. i can do this easy in code behind if i use winform panel by 'Panel.Handle' but i DO NOT want to write any code behind!